# Бан через selenium

Tags: парсер, selenium

Возникает проблема при попытке спарсить [сайт](https://www.repco.co.nz/). Захожу через прокси-сервер в хроме, то всё хорошо и он пускает. Забирать данные гет-запросами, даже со всеми хедерами не получается. Сразу прилетает бан. Selenium также каким-то образом вычисляется и банится. Как решить проблему с детекцией селениума? Какие механизмы лежат в основе того, что просто get-запросы детектятся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843380/ban-through-selenium) мой вопрос на en.SO. А также, [ещё один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver), старый вопрос. Мне посоветовали использовать следующее `--disable-blink-features` и `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`. Это решает проблему